# Is it possible to track by Bluetooth headphones

Tags: mac-address, bluetooth

Is it possible to find bluetooth device if I have MAC of the device.

Answer (score 2):

## Not unless you are in range of the device.

And even then, there are caveats, such as

- You can only track signal strength, so you need at least three measurement devices to track a location approximately.
- You can't know if a one MAC address corresponds to one or multiple devices.
- You can only track if Bluetooth is activated and actively sending out beacons or responding to requests

Comment: I differentiate **track** vs **locate**, although _find_ suggests _locate_ in the question. Many businesses _track_ customers via detecting their Bluetooth devices as they enter/exit the store, or even by area in larger stores or malls.

Comment: @user10216038 That is true, although I interpreted the question as "Is it possible to detect the location of a bluetooth device with a known MAC address at any given time?". You are right, though. I should have asked for clarification.